# InstallShield - .net prerequisities

Tags: .net, deployment, installshield

I have a .net 4.5 application which I'm deploying with Install Shield.

I have marked the .net 4.5 full re-distributable in the project so it is checked and downloaded if not installed on the target machine.

Do I also need to check .net 1, 1.1, 2.0 and 3.5?

If the installer is run on a new machine with no .net at all installed. will the web application run if only .net 4.5 is installed by the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the one framework version you are targeting.  So, including just the 4.5 should be ok.  But you should be testing these scenarios in your testing as well.

Comment: ok, thanks, ill create a VM, uninstall all .net versions and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, it "should" work, but I've found that if I don't test it there always ends up being something that doesn't work the way I thought it would.